# Laravel generate models, views and controllers from database or migration script

Tags: laravel, controller, view, models, reverse-engineering

I am new to Laravel 4. I wanted to know if it is possible to generate Models , Views and Controllers from existing database? I Googled and found

```
https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators
```

But it allow to generate migration script, model, views and controllers by providing resource name where as i want to reverse engineering of the same in which by command line i want to create models, views and controllers from the existing database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
php artisan generate:model dbtablename
```

it will create individual model from your existing database. In this case you **won't need** the `generate:resource` command.

```
php artisan generate:resource command
```

[Laravel-4 Generators](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-4-Generators) is very well documented. Read it thoroughly and you have fun.

If you're using Laravel 5, you might want to consider the [Laravel 5 Extended Generators](https://github.com/laracasts/Laravel-5-Generators-Extended) package.

Comment: I think it will generate empty model and how can we create controller and view from a model?

Comment: of course it will generate empty model and you can not create controller and view from a model."laravel-4 generators" help you create model,view and controller from command terminal.check out this tutorials. http://andrewperkins.net/laravel

Comment: you can also [check this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-power-of-laravel-generators--pre-41574). Jeffrey's tutorial on laravel 4 generators.

Comment: I believe the "Gii" tool that comes with Yii generates models with proper relations from a database schema. I think that is what the questions is addressing for Laravel? I too am looking for this but all Laravel-4-Generators seems capable of is generating empty model files even if the schema relations are all mapped out in migration files.

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same question, and couldn't find a good solution, so I started to build my own.

https://github.com/jimbolino/laravel-model-builder/

It's far from perfect, but is able to do the basic things like:

- Generate models
- Detect relations (probably buggy)
- Detect dates, auto increments
- Hidden fields (if you add a mysql comment)

Answer (score 2):

[Laravel 4 Migrations Generator](https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator): Automatically generates your migrations from an existing database schema. You will also find there the solution for Laravel-5.

At [packalyst.com](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/ignasbernotas/laravel-model-generator) you will find how to generate the model automatically.